# mysql table structure many to many

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, many-to-many

in a database for a forum I have POSTS table and TOPICS table.
Currently the representation of a thread is in the posts table as parent_id field.
a thread (collection of posts) can have many topics and vice versa so it's many2many relationship between threads and topics.

However, there is no "threads" table and it doesn't feel right to create one when the only field is thread id.
On the other hand connecting posts to topics doesn't seem efficient either because the topics are related to a thread, not to a single post...
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the question?  It sounds like you have posts.parent_ID alias "Thread" which is a one to one with topics but since a post can have many threads, a post could have many topics through the threads.... or is it that a thread itself could have many topics in which case you need an associative table postThreadTopics table linking the thread to it's multiple topics...

Comment: It's the second option you mentioned and thread has many posts, not the other way around. However, what will be the foreign keys to that associative table?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is an association table or junction table. Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of that solution to resolve common many to many relationship between to tables. Do you refer to topics2threads table or topics2posts table?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm If well then you will need another table maybe post_topic as an example but I don't know if that is going to be good for you there you will have this structure

post-topic
-id autoincrement PK
-pt_post_id FK
-pt_topic_id FK
-pt_thread_description

There you can manage the many to many and haves an unique autoincrement id rmaking reference to the thread and you can reference to both tables topic and posts

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure it's the optimal solution since there will be many disposable records because topic is per thread and not post...